# Is CountDownTimer cancelled automatically on Activity destroy()?

Tags: android, android-activity, countdowntimer, ondestroy

A question, maybe a little naive...

If I start a 2 minute CountDownTimer in Activity onCreate() and close it with finish() when user clicks a button, does Android cancel it automatically?

Or do I need to explicitly call cancel() in onDestroy()?

Comment: Have you ever tried it? Just put a Log.d(...) in `onFinish()` and see if it is logged.

Comment: Just tried. onFinish() seems alive even after an Activity.finish().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to explicitly call `cancel` in `Ondestroy`. But better practice is to call `cancel` in `Onpause`.
Since if you have paused your activity and you update any Ui elements inside `OnFinish` of the countdown timer it may throw errors.

Comment: Actually onDestroy() is much better and a straight-forward approach. The CountDownTimer won't throw any errors even if its onFinish() is called during onPause(). I tried it.